# How to draw rectangle in onBindViewHolder for RecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to draw a rectangle when onBindViewHolder is called. How would I do so?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

}
```

I've tried googling it, but there doesn't seem to be any examples on doing so.

Comment: You're gonna need to be more specific - where do you want to draw the rectangle?  Why specifically when onBindViewHolder is called - is this some sort of debugging feature to detect unnecessary rebinding?

Comment: I have an ImageView loaded with Glide in my onBindViewHolder and I want to draw the rectangle relative to an area on the imageview

Comment: For a solid rectangle: add a `View` with its background set to whatever color.  For an outline, you could do the same with the background set to a Drawable with a stroke.

Comment: didn't think of that for some reason... I was just tunnel visioning on something to do with trying to draw on canvas because thats how it's done with ItemDecoration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a solid rectangle, you could simply add a `View` with its `android:background` set to the desired color.  For an outline, you could do the same with the background set to a `Drawable` with a [`<stroke>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#stroke-element).